# How to use the word "concern" in other ways?

Tags: grammar

CONTEXT:

"Concerned" by the misuse of law, which provides 1 year jail term for hurting religious sentiments, the court limited the applicability of penal provision to malicious act.

How can I reframe this context so that the word "concern" does not come first?
Can I use some prepositions before "concern"?

Answer (score 0):

What about

> The court limited the applicability of penal provision to malicious
>   act because it was concerned by the misuse of law, which provides 1
>   year jail term for hurting religious sentiments.

For readability however, one could also make two scentences from this single one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want "concerned" to come first, you could simply swap the clauses:

> The court limited the applicability of penal provision to malicious act, concerned by the misuse of law, which provides 1 year jail term for hurting religious sentiments.

But if you want to begin with a prepositional phrase, as mentioned, you could write:

> **Out of concern for** the misuse of law, which provides 1 year jail term for hurting religious sentiments, the court limited the applicability of penal provision to malicious act.